# Im stuck on disk utility and can't get my operating system to install?

Tags: disk-utility

Don't know where to go from here? 
I've been going around in circles for hours. 
I have a bootable USB drive with Sierra on it, but I get to the install disk and my HD doesn't show.

Comment: have you entered the BIOS (before booting to USB) and ensured that the HDD is listed and enabled on an SATA channel (or other appropriate interface)?

Comment: No sir I don't know how to do that...?

Comment: Please don't cross-post almost similar [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288932/im-in-internet-recovery-mode-where-to-from-here-to-install-a-new-system) to several SE sites.

Comment: check the manual for your motherboard. Most manuals can be downloaded from the manufacturer.